# Key error when superclass of ordereddict calls popitem

Tags: python, data-structures, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to implement a cache via `Collections.OrderedDict`. I found a recipe in the python docs that does just this by extending the `OrderedDict` class. I'm wondering why my modification of the **setitem** method causes a keyerror.

```py
class LRU(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, maxsize=128, *args, **kwds):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        self.move_to_end(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if len(self) > self.maxsize:
            oldest = next(iter(self))
            del self[oldest]
```

This implementation of `__setitem__` causes a `KeyError` when we add an item while the cache is full and it seems to call `__getitem__` inside `popitem`.

```py
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if len(self) > self.maxsize:
            super().popitem()
```

---

```py
lru = LRU(3)
lru[1] = 1
lru[2] = 4
lru[3] = 9
lru[4] = 16
```

The code above gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hrishikeshdharam/Documents/play/lru.py", line 25, in <module>
    lru[4] = 16
  File "/Users/hrishikeshdharam/Documents/play/lru.py", line 18, in __setitem__
    super().popitem()
  File "/Users/hrishikeshdharam/Documents/play/lru.py", line 10, in __getitem__
    self.move_to_end(key)
KeyError: 4
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why does the second implementation of __setitem__ cause a key error? Sorry, I will clarify the post

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your version of `__setitem__`? In other words, why don't you just use the version in the recipe?

Comment: I was confused why the recipe used del instead of popnode. Now I'm just curious why it doesn't work with popnode. This is just for my understanding

Comment: The reason has something to do with how the `OrderedDict` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py) works. Regardless, your version doesn't really make much sense because it's trying to remove the thing it just added (because that's `popitem()`'s default behavior).  By analyzing the source code, you theoretically should also be able to figure out why the recipe uses `del` instead of `popnode()` — maybe it's simply because it doesn't work because of how things are currently implemented.